# Return index of Linkedlist node when value found

Tags: c++, linked-list

How does one simply return the index of a node in linkedlist when a value within the list is searched for and found?
Below is my attempt.

```
int find(Node* head, const int& n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (head->value != 10000){
        if(head == nullptr){
            std::cout << "value not found " << std::endl;
            return -1;
            break;
        }

        //if count equal too n return node->data 
        if( head->value == n){
            std::cout << "value found at index " << count << std::endl;
            return head->value;
            break;
        }

        //recursively decrease n and increase  
        // head to next pointer  
        return find(head->next, n-1);
        ++count;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. Indexed access to a linked list is *O(N)*. You want to return the value, possibly by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. you are not checking if `head` is null before accessing `head->value`, you are checking for null after.
2. if `n` is found on a node, you return the node's `value`, not the *index* of the node, which is what you are asking for.
3. you are using recursion when an iterative loop would be preferred and safer instead.
4. `n` is the value you are looking for, but you are decrementing it on each recursive call.  `n` is not an index, and should not be modified at all.
5. When you perform the recursive call, the final result of `find()` will be the result of the last comparison, not the cumulative result of all of the comparisons.  Worse, if your `while` loop ends without reaching any `return` statement, then the final result of `find()` will be *undefined*.

If you are going to use recursion, then it should look more like this:

```cpp
int find(Node* head, int n) {
    if (!head) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (head->value == n){
        return 0;
    }
    int result = find(head->next, n);
    return (result == -1) ? result : 1  + result;
} 

...

int index = find(head, 10000);
if (index != -1)
    std::cout << "value found at index " << index << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "value not found " << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/XfhhoO)

However, an iterative loop would be better:

```cpp
int find(Node* head, int n) {
    int index = -1;
    while (head) {
        ++index;
        if (head->value == n) {
            return index;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FRhZUd)

Comment: Thank you Sir! The iterative version is what I was attempting to do but I couldn't get my counter variable to properly increment.

Comment: How would one deallocate memory and set corresponding pointer variables to null? I utilized a destructor in the Node class definition, any other suggestions?

Comment: There is no memory being allocated manually in this code, so there is nothing to deallocate manually. Whatever problem you are having with memory management is not related to this code, so please post a separate question about it.

Comment: Okay, just unfamiliar with the method you utilized to construct the linked list in the second demo.